# Get last characters while character != "_"

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have string like

```
string test = "http://example.com/upload/user/80_747.jpg"
string test2 = "http://example.com/upload/user/80_4747.jpg"
```

In both cases i need "747" or "4747". Is there any auto or pre-made function for this or i need to do it fully manual.

ASP.NET C# 4.0

Comment: There is no framework method which will return a filename fragment like that. You will need to write some code.

Comment: Look up how to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split string with _ character and take the last string of result array then again split it with . character and take the first string of result array.

in JS

```
test.split('_')[1].split('.')[0];
```

in CS use SubString and IndexOf methods of String class.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression should work fine for this. Something like `@"_(\d+)\."`.

```
Regex.Match ("http://example.com/upload/user/80_747.jpg",   @"_(\d+)\.")
    .Groups[1]
    .Captures[0]
    .Value
```

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to make sure it's the last match, otherwise it will match the wrong underscore in "trick_123.treat_245.doc "

Comment: Let's leave it as exercise for OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
int startIndex = test.LastIndexOf('_');
int endIndex = test.LastIndexOf('.');
return test.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Since you're using .net4, and if your string format is as stated now, you can do it with linq:

```
return new string(test.SkipWhile(x=>x!='_').Skip(1).TakeWhile(x=>x!='.').ToArray());
```

Comment: Actually `Enumerable.SkipWhile` was introduced with 3.5 not 4

Comment: @ConradFrix, he wrote *ASP.NET C# 4.0* in his last paragraph, because of this I mentioned that if he talks about .net4.

Comment: ah that makes sense. Perhaps "Since you're using .Net 4..." might be clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.IO.Path` to [get the filename without the extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).  You will need to parse the fragment that you want out of that filename manually.  Using the framework to do that much, over straight regex of the whole path, will be slightly less error prone if, say, there was a '_' in one of the folder names.

Comment: @BalaR Don't think so, no.  There are other methods that will though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `test.LastIndexOf('_')` to find the last occurence of the _ character.

Answer (score 0):

```
string val = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(test.Substring(test.LastIndexOf('_') + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test
    .ToCharArray()
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(c =>
    {
        int i;
        return !int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out i);
    })
    .TakeWhile(c => c != '_');
```

I think it's foolproof for your requirement.